# Batch file writes wrong data onto file

Tags: batch-file

I'm a programmer in batch and I've just joined this site to ask 1 question...

I made this program that writes random numbers from 1 to 10 and encodes/writes them into a file... The problem is, ANOTHER Batch file must read the numbers and check if it's below 5.

The batch file that generates random numbers is not inputting a random number into the file;
Instead, the file says

> ECHO is off

Which confuses the other batch file, and therefore it crashes.

Here's the code of both batch files;

The "Writer" of the numbers

```
    @echo off >nul
    title Batch Arithmetic Communicator
    :check
    timeout /t 1 >nul /nobreak
    echo %t% >>wait.rsm
    SET /A t=%RANDOM% * 10 / 32768 + 1
    goto cont

    :cont
    timeout /t 1 >nul
    if exist pack.rsm goto cont2
    if NOT exist pack.rsm goto cont

    :cont2
    set /p data=<pack.rsm
    del pack.rsm
    if %data% LSS 5 goto move
    if %data% GTR 5 goto check

The receiver of the numbers


@echo off
:a
timeout /t 1 >nul
if exist wait.rsm goto b
if NOT exist wait.rsm goto a

:b
set /p d=<wait.rsm
if %d% GTR 5 goto a
if %d% LSS 5 goto w

:w
echo 3>>pack.rsm
goto a
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your writer is echoing %t% *before* it's setting it:

```
echo %t% >>wait.rsm
SET /A t=%RANDOM% * 10 / 32768 + 1
```

At the time of that first statement, `%t%` is set to nothing so it's as if you said:

```
echo >>wait.rsm
```

which is why you're getting `ECHO is off`, what you see with a "naked" echo command.

Basically, you need to set `%t` before trying to echo it so swap those two statements around:

```
SET /A t=%RANDOM% * 10 / 32768 + 1
echo %t% >>wait.rsm
```

Comment: `>>wait.rsm echo %t%` If you use this then it will not include a trailing space.